# How can I check the memory bank count in SuperMicro MBM-CMM-001?

Tags: memory, dedicated-server, supermicro

How can I check the memory bank count in SuperMicro MBM-CMM-001?

[image]

I checked all BIOS item, only can find the total memory.

Comment: Do you mean the count of installed memory modules or the count of max. memory banks?

Comment: This can't be found in the BIOS.